# use Android as real Gamepad (Not keyboard mapping)

Tags: applications, game-controllers

I've tested quite a few apps that let you use your Android as a real gamepad, but all of them just map you Android to your keyboard.
I wanted it to be recognized as a really controller, to be able to play multiplayer games locally with friends because i don't have any controller. Is there any way to do this? I don't have controllers for everyone nor do i have the money to by 4 controllers, i'm trying to find an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Droidjoy does this that you want, but be aware that since it requires a server application, it can only be used on a PC.